# show success message in PowerShell

Tags: 2013, powershell

I wrote a simple script with try and catch block, I want to show the success message with write host or any way in case the try code is executed! and hit catch in case there is any error as syntax error or the provided data is not correct !

PS: I am using -ErrorAction Stop ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerShell, there are two types of error

- **Terminating Error:** A serious error during execution that halts the command (or script execution) completely. Examples can include non-existent cmdlets, syntax errors that would prevent a cmdlet from running, or other fatal errors.
- **Non-Terminating Error:** A non-serious error that allows execution to continue despite the failure. Examples include operational errors such file not found, permissions problems, etc.

For more details check [An Introduction to Error Handling in PowerShell](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2013/06/09/an-introduction-to-error-handling-in-powershell/)

So,

- In the case of the **Termination error**, it will execute the catch section and terminated.
- In the case of the **Non-Termination error**, it will continue.even if there is an error or you provide incorrect information.

Thence if you need to make sure if the cmdlet executed successfully you should check if it's not equal null as the following:

Consider you need to `Get-SPWeb` for a specific URL

```
try
   {
  $result = Get-SPWe -Identity http://qassas
     if ($result -ne $null)
     {
     Write-Host "Success" -ForegroundColor Cyan
     }
     else
     {
     Write-Host "Failed" -ForegroundColor Red
     }
   }   
 catch
   {
     Write-Host "termination error" -ForegroundColor Red
   }
```

**At the above script try**

1. Provide correct URL, the result should be `Success`
2. Provide incorrect URL, the result should be `Failed`
3. Provide incorrect cmdlet like `Get-SPwe` , the result should be "`termination error`" at catch because it's incorrect cmdlet.

Comment: Why not just use $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop" and handle non-terminating errors correctly?

Comment: Great Suggestion @Bunzab , I think the author need to show success message and error message in case of non-termination error. that what I understood :)

Comment: @Bunzab i tried $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"  and get error a positional parameter cannot be found  that accept argument $null !!

Comment: @M.Qassas  clear explanation ! thank you for your usual help!